# How to write an explicit return type annotation for a recursive closure using JSDoc

Tags: typescript, recursion, closures, jsdoc

I have a fairly complex use case in a project which uses vanilla JS and checks types using `tsc` with type annotations written in JSDoc comments. I have a function which returns a function, and the returned function may recursively call itself, while also reassigning some closure variables.

Here is a silly example which gets the point across and will throw the same error:

```
/**
 * @returns {function(): number}
 */
function circular() {
  let num = Math.random();

  return function tryAgain() {
    if (num < 0.5) {
      return num;
    }

    num = Math.random();
    return tryAgain();
  };
}
```

So, if I run a typecheck on this code using `tsc`:

```
tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit --strict --target ES2017 *.js
```

I get the following error:

```
error TS7023: 'tryAgain' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.
```

To begin with, this error seems pretty erroneous. I clearly have an explicit return type annotation, which is the solution proposed for [similar circular references](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26623) using proper TypeScript rather than JSDoc.

But I'd be happy with any workaround that will get this to compile without a massive refactor that removes closures and/or recursion. I have already tried a number of possible workarounds, none of which have worked.

Wrapping the return function with an annotation:

```
  return /** @type {function(): number} */ (function tryAgain() {
    . . .
  });
```

Wrapping the recursive call with an annotation:

```
    return /** @type {number} */ (tryAgain());
```

Wrapping the recursive call with coercion:

```
    return Number(tryAgain());
```

At this point I'm totally stumped on how to annotate this properly, or at the very least how to get the darn thing to compile.

Comment: *"...and checks types using tsc with type annotations written in JSDoc comments..."* Well that's...really flippin' cool. I didn't know `tsc` supported doing that. Wow.

Comment: Side note: Function *declarations* don't have `;` after them (e.g., no `;` after the closing `}` of `circular`). They don't cause a problem, because JavaScript supports the *EmptyStatement*, but...

Comment: Indeed. It can be a pain, I think just using regular TS with a compile step is generally preferable. But it is definitely cool to have the option.

Comment: I think I'd opt for TypeScript as well (more concise, for one thing), but it's still cool to have the option. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating the function definition from the `return` lets you annotate `tryAgain`, which gets rid of the error:

```
/**
 * @returns {function(): number}
 */
function circular() {
  let num = Math.random();

  /**
   * @returns {number}
   */
  function tryAgain() {
    if (num < 0.5) {
      return num;
    }

    num = Math.random();
    return tryAgain();
  }

  return tryAgain;
}
```

Doing it inline also works:

```
/**
 * @returns {function(): number}
 */
function circular() {
  let num = Math.random();

  return /** @returns {number} */ function tryAgain() {
    if (num < 0.5) {
      return num;
    }

    num = Math.random();
    return tryAgain();
  };
};
```